# systemd[1]: apport-autoreport.service: Failed with result 'start-limit-hit'

Tags: systemd, apport

systemd is using 100% continually ... here is top

```
top - 19:47:09 up 13 min,  1 user,  load average: 3.26, 2.62, 1.69
Tasks: 306 total,   4 running, 294 sleeping,   0 stopped,   8 zombie
%Cpu(s): 35.5 us, 12.6 sy,  0.0 ni, 51.9 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem :  11858.2 total,   5183.4 free,   3433.2 used,   3241.6 buff/cache
MiB Swap:   2048.0 total,   2048.0 free,      0.0 used.   7913.7 avail Mem 

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                    
      1 root      20   0  268660 110536   8532 R 100.0   0.9  11:39.36 systemd                                                                                    
    772 message+  20   0   10988   6768   4116 R  46.0   0.1   5:16.01 dbus-daemon                                                                                
    259 root      19  -1  496536 327492 325464 S  16.8   2.7   2:16.95 systemd-journal                                                                            
    796 syslog    20   0  221104   5832   4052 S  13.9   0.0   1:38.00 rsyslogd                                                                                   
    804 root      20   0  103380  93880   7784 S  13.1   0.8   1:34.41 systemd-logind                                                                             
     18 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.7   0.0   0:00.55 ksoftirqd/1                                                                                
   1733 root      20   0  352968 130376  83760 S   0.7   1.1   0:25.47 Xorg                                                                                       
   1916 ava       20   0 4008000 272576 117864 S   0.7   2.2   0:32.40 gnome-shell                                                                                
   3877 ava       20   0 2629148 269672 162688 S   0.7   2.2   0:09.53 Web Content
```

here is the system log

```
 sudo tail -n 100 /var/log/syslog
Aug 13 19:46:11 kiev systemd[1]: Failed to start Process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled.
Aug 13 19:46:11 kiev systemd[1]: apport-autoreport.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Aug 13 19:46:11 kiev systemd[1]: apport-autoreport.service: Failed with result 'start-limit-hit'.
Aug 13 19:46:11 kiev systemd[1]: Failed to start Process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled.
Aug 13 19:46:11 kiev systemd[1]: apport-autoreport.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Aug 13 19:46:11 kiev systemd[1]: apport-autoreport.service: Failed with result 'start-limit-hit'.
Aug 13 19:46:11 kiev systemd[1]: Failed to start Process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled.
Aug 13 19:46:11 kiev systemd[1]: apport-autoreport.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Aug 13 19:46:11 kiev systemd[1]: apport-autoreport.service: Failed with result 'start-limit-hit'.
Aug 13 19:46:11 kiev systemd[1]: Failed to start Process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled.
Aug 13 19:46:11 kiev systemd[1]: apport-autoreport.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Aug 13 19:46:11 kiev systemd[1]: apport-autoreport.service: Failed with result 'start-limit-hit'.
Aug 13 19:46:11 kiev systemd[1]: Failed to start Process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled.
Aug 13 19:46:11 kiev systemd[1]: apport-autoreport.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Aug 13 19:46:11 kiev systemd[1]: apport-autoreport.service: Failed with result 'start-limit-hit'.
Aug 13 19:46:11 kiev systemd[1]: Failed to start Process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled.
Aug 13 19:46:11 kiev systemd[1]: apport-autoreport.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Aug 13 19:46:11 kiev systemd[1]: apport-autoreport.service: Failed with result 'start-limit-hit'.
Aug 13 19:46:11 kiev systemd[1]: Failed to start Process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled.
Aug 13 19:46:11 kiev systemd[1]: apport-autoreport.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Aug 13 19:46:11 kiev systemd[1]: apport-autoreport.service: Failed with result 'start-limit-hit'.
Aug 13 19:46:11 kiev systemd[1]: Failed to start Process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled.
Aug 13 19:46:11 kiev systemd[1]: apport-autoreport.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Aug 13 19:46:11 kiev systemd[1]: apport-autoreport.service: Failed with result 'start-limit-hit'.
Aug 13 19:46:11 kiev systemd[1]: Failed to start Process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled.
Aug 13 19:46:11 kiev systemd[1]: apport-autoreport.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Aug 13 19:46:11 kiev systemd[1]: apport-autoreport.service: Failed with result 'start-limit-hit'.
```

here is some of dmesg

```
[    3.942656] systemd[1]: Inserted module 'autofs4'
[    4.005635] systemd[1]: systemd 246-2ubuntu1 running in system mode. (+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +ZSTD +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD +IDN2 -IDN +PCRE2 default-hierarchy=hybrid)
[    4.025381] systemd[1]: Detected architecture x86-64.
[    4.046020] systemd[1]: Set hostname to <kiev>.
[    4.132974] systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/docker.socket:6: ListenStream= references a path below legacy directory /var/run/, updating /var/run/docker.sock → /run/docker.sock; please update the unit file accordingly.
[    4.137916] systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/dbus.service:12: Unit configured to use KillMode=none. This is unsafe, as it disables systemd's process lifecycle management for the service. Please update your service to use a safer KillMode=, such as 'mixed' or 'control-group'. Support for KillMode=none is deprecated and will eventually be removed.
[    4.164397] systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/plymouth-start.service:17: Unit configured to use KillMode=none. This is unsafe, as it disables systemd's process lifecycle management for the service. Please update your service to use a safer KillMode=, such as 'mixed' or 'control-group'. Support for KillMode=none is deprecated and will eventually be removed.
[    4.193000] systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/gdm.service:30: Standard output type syslog is obsolete, automatically updating to journal. Please update your unit file, and consider removing the setting altogether.
```

this happened after my last system update ... same after reboot and/or another system update ... any ideas ?

ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**old obsolete solution see below UPDATE for better approach**

just shut off the out of control service `apport`

```
sudo systemctl disable apport-autoreport 
#  sudo apt-get purge apport    #  avoid it works yet is too heavy handed
sudo apt-get purge apport-noui
```

then after a reboot systemd cpu usage was normal yet

```
tracker-miner-fs
```

was using 100% cpu even after another reboot so I issued

```
gsettings set org.freedesktop.Tracker.Miner.Files crawling-interval -2  
gsettings set org.freedesktop.Tracker.Miner.Files enable-monitors false
echo y | LANG=en tracker reset --hard
```

now all is well

**UPDATE**

edit file  `/usr/lib/systemd/system/apport-autoreport.path`

```
#  PathExistsGlob=/var/crash/*.crash  #  <-- old bad comment it out

PathChangedGlob=/var/crash/*.crash    #  good new replaces above line
```

save then issue

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

for details see  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apport/+bug/1891657

Here we are months later after this issue has been resolved below is contents from a healthy normal box  (  Ubuntu 20.04  as of 20210812 )

```
cat /usr/lib/systemd/system/apport-autoreport.path 

[Unit]
Description=Process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled (file watch)
ConditionPathExists=/var/lib/apport/autoreport

[Path]
PathExistsGlob=/var/crash/*.crash

[Install]
WantedBy=paths.target
```

Comment: You might try removing the package 'apport-noui' instead of removing apport altogether as apport is part of most desktop tasks.

Comment: After your updated solution, do you reboot, or does the systemctl command stop the journald process?

Comment: @JasonMehmel  I cannot recall however my guess is box was OK after issuing the daemon reload command otherwise I would have mentioned it needed a reboot

Comment: @ScottStensland fair enough! I tried your solution and got an error at the daemon reload command, but this was also after an upgrade to 21.04 so it's possible there were other things in play! I ended up just hard rebooting my machine and the journald cpu usage stopped.

Answer (score 3):

As a temporary workaround:
Delete all files under /var/crash/
It is not a long or even medium term solution, but better then nothing for a start.

Comment: /var/crash/   dir only contains one file ... which is left from an unrelated crash earlier