# /sbin/init splash high CPU usage

Tags: 20.04, systemd, cpu, init

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 and since a week the fan of my laptop spins constantly.
There are also major performance dropouts where the system seems to halt for a few seconds.

Now I had the time to take a closer look at it and noticed, that `/sbin/init splash` is constantly eating around 25% CPU time. I have an encrypted partition, is that to blame?

Comment: "I have an encrypted partition, is that to blame?" No. I had this issue on 16.??, with no encryption. Splash is evil. Unfortunately, I have no more information on this.

Answer (score 0):

Short: [look here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1267204/1130948)

It seems, `init splash` is not itself to blame.
Looking longer at the problem I saw, `systemd-journald` process also had peaks in CPU Usage.

Checking `journalctl` it was packed full with this:

```
systemd[1]: apport-autoreport.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
systemd[1]: apport-autoreport.service: Failed with result 'start-limit-hit'.
systemd[1]: Failed to start Process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled.
```

And that's a problem that is [already solved](https://askubuntu.com/a/1267204/1130948) and worked for me as well.

But why htop associated this with `init splash`? Well that's another question.