# What is a reasonable time frame for whoopsie-upload-all and systemd-journald to process? Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: 21.04, whoopsie

I recently upgraded to 21.04 and after rebooting and installing upgrades, I've been finding one of my four cpu cores is generally at 100% constantly, with the **whoopsie-upload-all** command. It's been that way for about an hour so far.

I don't have a problem with uploading error and crash reports but the amount of CPU is now affecting my ability to work!

EDIT:
The whoopsie process did finish, it just took longer than expected. Now I've got systemd-logind and systemd-journald taking up a bunch of CPU. I wonder if this is just part of the process after upgrading between Ubuntu versions?

I'm letting it run, but I've also tried the updated solution here:

[systemd[1]: apport-autoreport.service: Failed with result 'start-limit-hit'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1267010/systemd1-apport-autoreport-service-failed-with-result-start-limit-hit)

*FURTHER UPDATE*

the **daemon-reload** command didn't work, and journald continued to consistently chew up my CPU, so I eventually powered off the machine and rebooted.

There were a few error reports that came up after the reboot, and I sent them in, but no systemd or journald high-cpu usage anymore. I'm not sure if this was a loop or if the solution I tried above actually worked!

Comment: This may **not** be a duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/q/135540/124466. The answers to that may not be applicable anymore.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that. I don't mind sending error reporting, I'm just not sure how long this should take. If it's been a few hours, and the crash logs aren't that big... even having a progress bar for this would help give me a sense of if this is an error or problem, or just a correctly working program I should just let finish!

Comment: It's generally safe to kill a whoopsie process. After a while, it will try to upload again. One assumes your network is working properly. Are you on a network that requires a proxy to reach daisy.ubuntu.com? Can you ping and/or traceroute that server successfully?

Comment: I haven't tried that!

Comment: The whoopsie process did finish, it just took longer than expected. Now I've got systemd-logind and systemd-journald taking up a bunch of CPU. I wonder if this is just part of the process after upgrading between Ubuntu versions.

Comment: Edit your question to put all these information.